# reading all the columns from CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I'm very new to C#. I need to read all the columns from the CSV file.
In my CSV i have: Date, test1 (under test1 there are some random data), lowerlimit (lowest number from the test1 data which is copied same in all the rows of lowerlimit. And last column is higherlimit (highest number from the test1 data ).

This is for calculating process capability.

I have found the following code which reads only the first column.
But i need to read all the columns

```
 public static DataTable OpenCSV(string filePath)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string strLine = "";
        string[] aryLine = null;
        string[] tableHead = null;
        int columnCount = 0;       
        bool IsFirst = true;
        while ((strLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (IsFirst == true)
            {
                tableHead = strLine.Split(',');
                IsFirst = false;
                columnCount = tableHead.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                {
                    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(tableHead[i]);
                    dt.Columns.Add(dc);                     
                }
            }
            else
            {
                aryLine = strLine.Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                {
                    dr[j] = aryLine[j];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        if (aryLine != null && aryLine.Length > 0)
        {
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = tableHead[0] + " " + "asc";
        }
        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();
        return dt;
    }

    DataTable dt;

    public int Val1 { get; private set; }
    public int Val2 { get; private set; }
    public int Cp { get; private set; }

    private void btOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = OpenCSV(textBox1.Text);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            // Get the first column
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(dr["Date"]);  
        }
```

I expect to make some calculations after reading all the columns on the file

Comment: Never write your own CSV reader. https://github.com/phatcher/CsvReader

Comment: This code read line by line. Split every line to columns and put columns to rows. Why you think it reads only first column?

Comment: can you please tell me what modifications should i make to read all the columns in my above code ( giving headers manually)

Comment: After splitting**

Comment: As @vik_78 said, it reads all columns already!

Comment: At first step it reads headers from file and calculate columns count. If you skip this step you should calculate count in data reading step.

Comment: after reading all the columns, I need to get Cp which is equal to = upper - lower limits/ 6 x std deviation

Comment: @AkshayShirahatti you should use some libraries instead of writing your own logic to play with CSV's one of them is https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

in  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows), your dr has all the columns. You can access the values by entering a different column name in the indexer. e.g. dr["test1"], dr["lowerlimit"], dr["higherlimit"] etc

Comment: Hi, I need to put all the data of tests in an array

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to read a csv file:

```
List<string> lstDates = new List<string>();
List<string> lstTest = new List<string>();
string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
foreach(string r in rows)
{
  string[] cols = r.split(',');
  lstDates.Add(cols[0]);
  lstTest.add(cols[1]);
  //you can add other columns to lists
}
//if you need the lists to be arrays you can convert them
string[] arrDates = lstDates.ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi,I did the splitting and getting the values from a CSV file. Now I need to add some math operations on those columns of csv . (i want to calculate process capability Cp,Cpk)

Comment: "adding some math operations" is a different issue I think, and you should google for it. Besides it is not clear what you want exactly. As a first glance I can suggest you; after getting the values to an array you can loop through it and convert to integer each element than make the calculations